# Grails - Duplicate property mapping of IndexBackref

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm facing a weird issue in grails (3.1.11) closely related to this blog post (from 2010 !):
http://codedumpblog.blogspot.de/2010/02/grails-many-to-many-with-lists.html

I'm trying to model the following simple relations:

- There are two parent types (`Organization` and `Person`) that share a child type (`Address`) in a `hasMany` association.
- An `Address` can only belong to one of the parents, never to both simultaneously.
- Deleting either an `Organization` or a `Person` should delete all its `Address`-es.

So far I have the following code:

```
class Organization {
    List addresses

    static hasMany = [addresses: Address]

    static mapping = {
        addresses sort: 'country', order: 'asc', cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}

class Person {
    List addresses

    static hasMany = [addresses: Address]

    static mapping = {
        addresses sort: 'country', order: 'asc', cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}

class Address {
    String country
    //...truncated...

    static belongsTo = [organization: Organization,
                        person  : Person]

    static constraints = {
        organization nullable: true
        person nullable: true
    }
}
```

But after running this I get the following Hibernate exception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of
>   _addressesIndexBackref found in com.example.Address

As in the blog post, the problem only shows up if the `addresses` field has the same name in both parent classes. If I rename the fields to `organizationAddresses` and `personAddresses` respectively, then everything works as expected.

I'd like the field to remain as just `addresses` though, so I don't have to call stuff like `organization.organizationAddresses` and `person.personAddresses`.

Is there a modern workaround for this almost 7 year old issue?

Comment: did you find some solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not - i just went with giving the fields different names.

Comment: I found the solution, will post it now

Comment: Changed the names, made it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

---

This looks like a **Hibernate Bug**. Occurs when you create a `Class` with **two relationships connected by** `many-to-one`

In your case, there are two classes related to `Address` by `hasMany`

---

**The Solution**

---

Replace the `membership` relationship by `use` relationship. In your case, this is done like this:

Create a class `ListAddresses` to hold the adresses of a `Person` or `Organization`:

```
class ListAddresses {
    List addresses

    static hasMany = [addresses: Address]

    static mapping = {
        addresses sort: 'country', order: 'asc', cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}
```

Delete all relationships from `Address` and create the new one:

```
class Address {
    String country
    //...truncated...

    static belongsTo = [list:ListAddresses]
    /*static belongsTo = [organization: Organization,
                    person  : Person]*/

    static constraints = {
        /*organization nullable: true
        person nullable: true*/
    }
}
```

Use `ListAddresses` in `Person` or `Organization`

```
class Organization {
    ListAddresses addresses

    static mapping = {
        addresses cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}

class Person {
    ListAddresses addresses

    static mapping = {
        addresses cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}
```

**This answer is based on the question**. But in my case, the solution was easier because I replace the `belongsTo` relationship and not `hasMany`.